# 404 Page not found with title name but working with id url only

Tags: laravel-10

Hello so the page actually works if I only get the url to the route but i also want to add the name but the page is giving me 404 page not found I'm using laravel 10 and I'm sure this is the right way since with id only the page is working but when I add product name it says 404 page not found I can't seem to find what is wrong

the url is correct already it get the name of an item

here is the code

route:

```
Route::prefix('product')->name('product.')->group(function(){
Route::get('/item/{id}/{$product_name}',[WebsiteController::class,'ShowItemProduct'])->name('item');
```

Controller:

```
public function ShowItemProduct(Request $request, $id = null,  $product_name = null){
    
        return view('website.pages.item')->with(['id'=>$id,'product_name'=>$product_name]);
        }
```

getting link

```
 <a href="{{route('product.item',[$product->id,preg_replace('/\+/','-',urlencode($product->product_name))])}}" type="submit">Show</a>
```

the page file structure

Website

> Pages
> --item (it should be link here)
> --productpage (this is the page of products item)

I tried researhing but it's not working

Comment: 'id' is already a unique parameter in your url, why you want a product name  again ? I don't know if it works but try changing "$product_name" to "product_name" only in the Route.

Comment: `error.message` should be `error.response.data.message`

Comment: hello abdulla i appreciate your comment but i can't seem to follow where to add that error.message? because i don't have anything about that

Comment: hello surya thanks for response i didn't see the problem it's working now thanks a lot you save my time i was close in wasting my time